# Djano first project search issue

Tags: python, django

This is the part of the project I'm stuck on:

Search: Allow the user to type a query into the search box in the sidebar to search for an encyclopedia entry.
If the query matches the name of an encyclopedia entry, the user should be redirected to that entry’s page.
If the query does not match the name of an encyclopedia entry, the user should instead be taken to a search results page that displays a list of all encyclopedia entries that have the query as a substring. For example, if the search query were Py, then Python should appear in the search results.
Clicking on any of the entry names on the search results page should take the user to that entry’s page.

my code:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.wiki, name="wiki"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
]
```

util.py

```
import re

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))


def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
    
def wiki(request, title):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/wiki.html", {
        "entries": util.get_entry(title)
    })
    
def search(request): 
    entries = util.list_entries()
    find_entries = list()

    search_box = request.POST.get("q").capitalize()

    if search_box in entries:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"wiki/{search_box}")
        
    for entry in entries:
        if search_box in entry:
           find_entries.append(entry)
        else:
            print(f'{find_entries}')
        
    if find_entries:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
          "search_result": find_entries,
          "search": search_box
    })
```

layout.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
               <form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Create New Page
                </div>
                <div>
                    Random Page
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

search.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    search results
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for result in search_result %}
        <li><a href=wiki/{{ result }}>{{ result }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <h1>{{ no_result }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Im getting the following error: AttributeError at /search
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'capitalize'

please help

Comment: replace this line `search_box = request.POST.get("q").capitalize()` with `search_box = request.POST.get("q", "").capitalize()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because the form in your layout.html template is using the `get` method, but the `search` function in your views.py is checking `request.POST`.

You will need to update the `search` function in views.py:

```py
search_box = request.POST.get("q").capitalize()  # remove this
search_box = request.GET.get("q").capitalize()  # add this
```

You can also remove the `{% csrf_token %}` in your layout.html template, as it is [not required for GET requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/).

Comment: ok now i don't get the error. However, instead of my matching searching going to my entry page for that listed item. It's going to my search page. For example, if i put CSS in the search it goes to the search page that list all my entries. Instead of my created wiki.html page

Comment: Ok. It seems that `if search_box in entries:` isn't returning True. Have you checked that the output of `util.list_entries()` is what you expect? What else have you tried to diagnose the problem?

Comment: yes it returns the list correctly, and it html them to appropriate entry...yes its not working as true for sure.  i think its in this part "if search_box in entry:
           find_entries.append(entry) " i think i need this needs to be replaced with running the wiki function. im just not sure how

Comment: i feel like i need to import wiki into the search function because im trying to add it t o list and thats not what i inted to do

Comment: I tried to do this: for entry in entries:
        if search_box in entry:
           return wiki (request, {"entries": util.get_entry(title)})
        else:
            print(f'{find_entries}') but it came back as NameError at /search
name 'title' is not defined

Comment: I'll have a look at the separate question you have posted regarding that issue. In the meantime, I suggest you upvote/accept any answers that have helped. You don't appear to have done that on any of your questions.